# THC and the Brain damage

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience

Are people who react badly(paranoia/more severe anxiety) to weed/THC at risk for damaging effects to the brain compared to the general population? 
  Does a certain type of brain chemistry/neuro disease get exacerbated from heavy THC usage contributing to substantial damage that is other wise not a problem?

Apparently an one of my dad's uncle had some condition that was worsened by weed and essentially retarded him.

Comment: Related: [How does Cannabis cause psychosis?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/18429/7001)